# Pygame lagging because of sprites?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, lag, platform

I made the game like this with sprites to make a platform game.

It was fine before but now it's lagging, so when the gravity is applied it moves by one and looks unnatural.

It was fine  at first, when the platforms were rectangles.

I changed the platforms and also inserted a list of enemies as sprites.

It does work fine but it is very laggy and it is very slow.
I don't like how the character is "stuttering". 
What can I do?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class Poppy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self): #making the player
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.image = pygame.image.load('POPPY.png')
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.grav = .5
       self.y_vel = 0
       self.jumping = False

   def jump_update(self): #checking the jumps
       if self.jumping:
           self.y_vel += self.grav
           self.rect.y += self.y_vel

   def jump(self): #the jump initializer
       if not self.jumping:
           self.y_vel = -50
           self.jumping = True

   def keys(self): #the keys
       key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
       dist = 5
       if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
           self.rect.x += dist # move right
       elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
           self.rect.x -= dist

   def collide_check(self, platform_list): #check if it hit the ground or the platforms
       for blocks in platform_list:
           if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, blocks) == True:
               self.rect.y = blocks.top

       if self.rect.y >= 600-self.rect.height:              # BALL HITS TOP AND BOTTOM
           self.grav = 0
           self.y_vel = 0
           self.rect.y = 600 - self.rect.height
           self.jumping = False

   def move(self):
       self.rect.x += 0
       self.rect.y += 10

   def draw(self, surface):
       surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):
       pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.image = pygame.image.load('levoneplatform.png')
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

 def __init__(self):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Menu():
   def setup(self):
       background_image = pygame.image.load('menu.png').convert_alpha()
       screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])


class LevOne():
   def setup(self):

       background_image = pygame.image.load('night.png').convert_alpha()
       screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])


       platforms_one = [ (200,300),
                       (50,500),
                       (550,650),
                       (300,200),
                       (120,100)
                  ]
       for k,v in platforms_one:
           platform = Platform()
           enemy = Enemy()
           platform.rect.x = k
           enemy.rect.x = k
           platform.rect.y = v
           enemy.rect.y = v - 44
           platform_list.add(platform)
           enemy_list.add(enemy)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
Poppy = Poppy()
Menu = Menu()
LevOne = LevOne()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
level = 0

while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()
      elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == K_SPACE:
              Poppy.jump()
              Poppy.jump_update()

  Menu.setup()
  if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
       x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
       if x >= 544.86 and x <= 700.86 and y <= 385.02 and y >= 340.03:
           level = 1

  if level == 1:

      first_lives = 5
      LevOne.setup()

      Poppy.keys()
      Poppy.move()


      Poppy.draw(screen)
      platform_list.draw(screen)
      enemy_list.draw(screen)


      Poppy.draw(screen)

  pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you're loading your LevOne background on every iteration, as well as initialising the various sprites. This is a one time operation, and so doing it on every iteration isn't necessary, and is probably causing the stuttering you're experiencing. You should load the background in an `__init__` of your LevOne class, along with whatever sprites will be used in the level, then access the background variable when blitting in the setup method.

Instead of this;

```
class LevOne():
   def setup(self):

       background_image = pygame.image.load('night.png').convert_alpha()
       screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])


       platforms_one = [ (200,300),
                       (50,500),
                       (550,650),
                       (300,200),
                       (120,100)
                  ]
       for k,v in platforms_one:
           platform = Platform()
           enemy = Enemy()
           platform.rect.x = k
           enemy.rect.x = k
           platform.rect.y = v
           enemy.rect.y = v - 44
           platform_list.add(platform)
           enemy_list.add(enemy)
```

Try this:

```
class LevOne():
   def __init__(self):
       self.background_image = pygame.image.load('night.png').convert_alpha()
       platforms_one = [ (200,300),
                       (50,500),
                       (550,650),
                       (300,200),
                       (120,100)
                  ]
       for k,v in platforms_one:
           platform = Platform()
           enemy = Enemy()
           platform.rect.x = k
           enemy.rect.x = k
           platform.rect.y = v
           enemy.rect.y = v - 44
           platform_list.add(platform)
           enemy_list.add(enemy)
   def setup(self):
       screen.blit(self.background_image, [0, 0])
```

The same issue is there for the Menu class I'm noticing. The same change should be made as follows.

```
class Menu():
   def __init__(self):
       self.background_image = pygame.image.load('menu.png').convert_alpha()
   def setup(self):
       screen.blit(self.background_image, [0,0])
```

I just want to reiterate the reason I believe this is running slowly is that it is having to open a file from the system upon every iteration, Which is a slow operation, and you also keep creating your sprite lists for level one, which only needs to be done once.